# Rewriting the jQuery validation errorPlacement output?

Tags: jquery-validate, errorplacement

Ok, I've got a bit of a complicated task (at least for me)... I need to rewrite the default errorPlacement output:

`<label for="name" generated="true" class="error" style="display: inline;">This field is required.</label>`

into something like this:

`<span class="error-msg qTipTitle" title="This field is required.">`

possible? if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

it is possible i did the same you can de it with `errorPlacement` and `errorClass`.
try reading the documentation on:

[jQuery site( .validate(options))](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options)

its in the options of the `.validate()`.
so you need it like: `$('#myform').validate(errorPlacement: function(error, element){ /* placement here */ }`

My code:

```
$('#Vdform').validate({
            // zegt waar de error moet staan!
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                error.appendTo(element.parent());
            },
            // hilights de error met de goede classes er op!
            highlight: function(elem){
                $(elem).parent().parent().addClass('error');
                $(elem).addClass('help-inline');
            },
            // un highlights de error as die gedaan is!
            unhighlight: function(elem){
                $(elem).parent().parent().removeClass('error');
                $(elem).removeClass('help-inline');
            },errorClass: "help-inline",
            errorElement: "span",
            focusCleanup : true
})
```

Comment: right... I figured out how to do addClass and all that, but how do I rewrite the actual error message to be part of the "title=..." section of the "span" tag...?

Comment: you can get the title message by `var title = $('span').attr('title');` and to set the Title to a span element you van use: `$('span').attr('title','title message here');` If you neeed to know whats the error message. you can after pace the error `error.appendTo(element.parent());` ask for whats in the span `var errormessage = element.parent().find('span').txt();` i think you are looking for: `errorPlacement: function(error, element) { error.appendTo(element.parent());element.parent().find('span').attr('title',element.parent().find('span').txt()); }, `